# Update props in react Hook form external function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

```
   **reactClass.js**

   <hookFunction tableData={[]} />
```

How can i update tableData from hookfunction below from its external function.
I expect update to happen onChange effect.

```
**hookFunction.js**

import React from 'react';

function TableR({ data }) {
   return (
    <input
      value={filterValue || ''}
      onChange={(e) => {
        // update props `tableData`
      }}
    />
  );
}

function App({tableData}) {
  return (

     return <Table  data={tableData} />;

  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hook `useState` with `useEffect` to listen for prop updates:

```
function TableR({ data, setTableData }) {
   return (
    <input
      value={filterValue || ''}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setTableData(e.target.value);
      }}
    />
  );
}

function App({tableData}) {
  const [data, setTableData] = useState(tableData);

  useEffect(() => {
    // this will update the state if tableData coming as props changes
    setTableData(tableData);
  }, [tableData]);

  return <Table  data={data} setTableData={setTableData} />;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: THanks @Rafael,  the thing is that i am using reguler function `TableR` hence not able to access `useEffect or useState` according to hooks rules.

Comment: you can use hooks in regular functions or arrow functions.

Comment: I have  just moved my function `TableR` inside hook function App() therefore able to to my updates accordingly. I dont know if thats best practice

Comment: Thanks will check out that.